# How i can integrate fingerprint scanning device in a PHP application

Tags: php, fingerprint, time-and-attendance

I am working on an attendance system in PHP, attendance will be recorded with fingerprint device (SUPEREMA). how I will integrate auto attendance through scanning device, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that PHP runs on a server, and a print scanner is going to be attached to a client machine? Unless the scanner dumps the digitized print into a form field or something, there's no way for PHP to talk to it directly.

Comment: @MarcB you can run PHP on 'client' machine as well. _But the question is too vague anyway, as there numerous different ways do do that._

Comment: every device has its own SDK, you want me to utilize that sdk, and then update my app database at the end of the day?

Comment: Marc B and c69 are just saying that there are several important questions that you haven't answered that need to be before a sensible answer can be made. Does SUPEREMA come with its own software, or does it have any open-source software available, or does it have a plugin framework? There are some easy ways to get data from one app to another, but they're very contingent on circumstances.

Comment: SUPEREMA comes with its own software.

Comment: Does that software has a documentation, an API reference, something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the SUPEREMA system does have a SDK

http://www.supremainc.com/eng/product/pc_22.php?mark=33

However it doesn't integrate with PHP. The only way I can see of doing it would be to write a Visual Studio app that captured and updated to the database, or one with an embedded html browser that it could then send the captured data to.

Answer (score 0):

Suprema includes now a Web Agent API with its SDK.

The Web Agent they provide is a Windows-based application that acts like a mini-web-server on the client side on a specific port. e.g., `https://localhost:5151`.

When a client visits your web application and they have the Web Agent up and running, you can do a cross-origin AJAX request with the help of Javascript to `https://localhost:5151/scan` that would return a base64 encoded image of the fingerprint.

---

Basically what they have done is to bridge the web browser to the internals of the client's computer.